# Schedule a cronjob on ssh with command line

Tags: ssh, cron

I am using the amazonaws es3 server.I want to schedule my cron with command line.
I am using the this command for scheduling the cron job

at -f shellscript.sh -v 18:30

but it will schedule for only one time i want to configure manually like once a day or every five minutes .

Please help with command which command i have to used

Thnaks,

Comment: I think this question is more suited to ServerFault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @The.Anti.9 noted, this kind of question fits in Serverfault.
To answer your question, crontab is a little more powerful than 'at' and gives you more flexibility as you can run the job repeatedly for instance daily, weekly, monthly.

For instance for your example, if you need to run the script every day at 18:30 you'd do this,

```
$ crontab -e
```

then add the following

```
30 18 * * * /path/to/your/script.sh
```

save and you are done.

Note: 30 18 indicates time 18:30, and *s indicate that it should run every day of every month) If you need to run it on a particular day of the month just check it out on the man page of crontab.

Comment: what do I do, if I want it to run at several specific times a day e.g. 9:00, 12:00 and 18:30 o'clock ? create 3 cronjobs or can I specify it in one?

Comment: @veritaS If the time duration between them is the same (say every hour) then one crontab is sufficient. If its not like your case, you'd need to have 3 entries. Check the crontab manpage or use [this generator](https://crontab-generator.org/)

Comment: I currently have it running with comma seperated values. You can do something like   30 5,11,18 * * * /path/to/your/script.sh which translates to at 5:30, 11:30 and18:30

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't crontab -e work?
and to generate crontab code http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jslibrary/demos/crontab.php should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `crontab -e` to edit your cron planned execution. A good explanation on how to set the time can be found on the [Ubuntu forum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)